# NewtonSoft json converter " unterminated String, expected delimiter : "; "

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to parse a json response that I get when calling a rest API.
The problem I am facing is that the deserializing doesn't work every time, even though I am making the same request. I don't know how to fix it since a try.catch is not making anything better.

Also, when I am trying to parse a very big response (20+ json objects) the program never works.

I have googled the problem myself but I don't know the solution..

> Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'drinks[0].strMeasure4', line 3, position 720.

is one of the errors I am getting, it is never the same.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleApplication1;

namespace TCPclient
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        client.Connect("www.thecocktaildb.com", 80); // geen http
        string request = getRequestCoctail("margarita");


        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(request);

        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];

        do
        {
            numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length);

            message.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));

        } while (stream.DataAvailable);


        string response = message.ToString();

        //Console.WriteLine("Response: \n" + response);
        response = response.Substring(response.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n"));
        try
        {
            dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
            List<Drink> drankjes = new List<Drink>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.drinks.Count; i++)
            {

                try
                {
                    string id = jsonData.drinks[i].idDrink;
                    string drink = jsonData.drinks[i].strDrink;
                    string category = jsonData.drinks[i].strCategory;
                    string instructions = jsonData.drinks[i].strInstructions;
                    string glass = jsonData.drinks[i].strGlass;
                    Console.WriteLine(glass);
                    var d = new Drink(id, drink, category, instructions);

                    drankjes.Add(d);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error");
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }


        //Console.WriteLine(jsonData.drinks.Count);


        //Console.WriteLine(jsonData.drinks.Count); get ammount of drinks.
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    //www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=15679
    private static string getRequestCoctail(string coctail)
    {

        ///api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita
        return $"GET /api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=godfather HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                 + "Host: www.thecocktaildb.com\r\n\r\n";
    }

    private static string GetMetaDataCocktail(dynamic jsonData)
    {

        dynamic drink = jsonData.drinks[0];
        return $"DrinkID : {drink.idDrink} \nDrinkName : {drink.strDrink} \nInstructions : {drink.strInstructions}";
    }

    private static Drink GenerateNewDrink(dynamic jsonData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(jsonData.idDrink, jsonData.strDrink, jsonData.strCategory, jsonData.strInstructions);
        return new Drink(jsonData.idDrink, jsonData.strDrink, jsonData.strCategory, "", jsonData.strInstructions);

    }
}
}
```

edit :

I added the drink class :

```
class Drink
{
    public readonly string drinkId;
    public readonly string strDrink;
    public readonly string strCategory;
    public readonly string strInstructions;
    public readonly string strGlass;

    public Drink(string drinkId, string strDrink, string strCategory, string strInstructions)
    {
        this.drinkId = drinkId;
        this.strDrink = strDrink;
        this.strCategory = strCategory;
        this.strInstructions = strInstructions;
    }

    public Drink(string drinkId, string strDrink, string strCategory, string strGlass, string strInstructions)
    {
        this.drinkId = drinkId;
        this.strDrink = strDrink;
        this.strCategory = strCategory;
        this.strGlass = strGlass;
        this.strInstructions = strInstructions;
    }
}
}
```

I tried it with :

http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=godfather

it went good for 5 times, then i got this error + the json i recieved.
the 6th time was fine aswell.

http://pastebin.com/c0d29L0S (Better format then the paste below)

Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path 'drinks[1].strIngredient1', line 3, position 1243.

```
{"drinks":[
{"idDrink":"11423",
"strDrink":"Godfather",
"strCategory":"Ordinary Drink",
"strAlcoholic":"Alcoholic",
"strGlass":"Old-fashioned glass",
"strInstructions":"Pour ingredients into an old-fashioned glass over ice and serve. (Bourbon may be substituted for scotch, if preferred.)",
"strDrinkThumb":null,
"strIngredient1":"Scotch",
"strIngredient2":"Amaretto",
"strIngredient3":"",
"strIngredient4":"",
"strIngredient5":"",
"strIngredient6":"",
"strIngredient7":"",
"strIngredient8":"",
"strIngredient9":"",
"strIngredient10":"",
"strIngredient11":"",
"strIngredient12":"",
"strIngredient13":"",
"strIngredient14":"",
"strIngredient15":"",
"strMeasure1":"1 1\/2 oz ",
"strMeasure2":"3\/4 oz ",
"strMeasure3":" ",
"strMeasure4":" ",
"strMeasure5":" ",
"strMeasure6":" ",
"strMeasure7":" ",
"strMeasure8":"",
"strMeasure9":"",
"strMeasure10":"",
"strMeasure11":"",
"strMeasure12":"",
"strMeasure13":"",
"strMeasure14":"",
"strMeasure15":"",
"dateModified":null
},
{"idDrink":"11538",
"strDrink":"J. R.'s Godfather",
"strCategory":"Ordinary Drink",
"strAlcoholic":"Alcoholic",
"strGlass":"Old-fashioned glass",
"strInstructions":"In an old-fashioned glass almost filled with ice cubes, combine both of the ingredients. Stir to mix the flavors.",
"strDrinkThumb":null,
"strIngredient1":
```

I understand why it goes wrong right now, the JSON is invalid ofcourse, but this is the response I recieved. So the code I am using to get the response is wrong.. right?

edit 3:

same request, good JSON response :

http://pastebin.com/e3WNxz0W

Now the program works, but it is incosistent.

Comment: Hi @kevin, I suggest you to put your json(which has some problem) in question. It's hard to find the problem without json details.

Comment: can you also add your Drink class

Comment: Try to capture the json data when you receive the error ans show it

Comment: Some of the string props, rather than an empty string such as for IngredXX are "\n" (text).  It will deserialize, but will be hard to work with.  I'd write a converter to fix/remove that and normalize Ingredients to its own type {Item, Measure}

Comment: If the json is bad, then it isn't json. Why are you trying to parse invalid json?

Comment: Are you sure your download code is retrieving all the text? When checking the link to the site it produced a full json whereas your json example is cutoff at the end.

Comment: And looking over your code looks like it has some issues. ASCII encoding? And you're decoding buffer by buffer, what if the text is really in UTF-8 and you get first of a multibyte character at the end of one buffer? You should rewrite your download code and see if that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: You actually have 2 problems/questions: a) issues with communicating and 2) grody structure sometimes with questionable data.  If you are using the test API key, that may be throttled as to how many requests per minute/second/something it will respond to.  Or it could just be FUBAR - only 269 drinks there.

Comment: @Plutonix , Did you remove your answer?

Comment: Yeah.  If the issue is processing the response or communicating (the Q sort of implies otherwise though). then it didnt really answer *this* question.  It almost looks like there is a size limit on the return they way it cuts off.

Comment: Well, like I said in the comment. Thanks for the answer, will check when I am home. Since I was at my work and could not check it. I wanted to try it out because it was the best answer......

Comment: FYI: I had this same issue and it was caused by a string containing a semicolon. The string was serialized, then saved to a cookie. Cookies can't contain semicolons, so it would truncate all of the json string after the semicolon. When we tried to retrieve and deserialize the cookie, it would throw an error due to the (now) malformed json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the actual problem is you're not evaluating the HTTP response headers.

The result is most likely sent in batches, i.e. the transfer encoding is "chunked", but your naive reader will only get the very first chunk and use that, rather than waiting for more. This might change between requests (e.g. chunked on direct delivery, non-chunked once cached or vice-versa). So in the end, don't reinvent the wheel, just use `WebClient`.

[Read up the RFC section 3.6.1:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1)

> **3.6.1 Chunked Transfer Coding**

> The chunked encoding modifies the body of a message in order to
> transfer it as a series of chunks, each with its own size indicator,
> followed by an OPTIONAL trailer containing entity-header fields. This
> allows dynamically produced content to be transferred along with the
> information necessary for the recipient to verify that it has
> received the full message.

---

When you're encountering an issue like this, try to split your code into smaller parts and check to see whether these parts deliver the expected results.

In your case, your HTTP download clearly appears to be incomplete, so you can't really blame the JSON parser for spitting out errors (because they're valid).

Comment: Problem was : HTTP 1.1 was used. When using HTTP 1.0 there are no problems. Why? HTTP 1.1 sends in chuncks.

Reason for TCPclient, had to use TCP client to learn how to work with it.

Answer (score 6):

I've reproduced your exception with the following unit test

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;

//using ConsoleApplication1;

namespace TCPclient
{
    [TestFixture]

    public class Program
    {
        [Test]
        public void Main1()
        {

            string response = GetCoctailString();
            try
            {
                dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
                List<Drink> drankjes = new List<Drink>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.drinks.Count; i++)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        string id = jsonData.drinks[i].idDrink;
                        string drink = jsonData.drinks[i].strDrink;
                        string category = jsonData.drinks[i].strCategory;
                        string instructions = jsonData.drinks[i].strInstructions;
                        string glass = jsonData.drinks[i].strGlass;
                        Console.WriteLine(glass);
                        var d = new Drink(id, drink, category, instructions);

                        drankjes.Add(d);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("error");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static string GetCoctailString()
        {
            return "{ 'drinks':[{'idDrink':'15679','strDrink':'Midori Margarita','strCategory':'Ordinary Drink','strAlcoholic':'Alcoholic','strGlass':'Cocktail glass','strInstructions':'Moisten rim of cocktail glass with lime juice and dip in salt. Shake ingredients together, and pour into glass filled with crushed ice. Option: Mix above ingredients with one cup of ice in blender for a smooth, \"granita\" type drink.','strDrinkThumb':null,'strIngredient1':'Tequila','strIngredient2':'Triple sec','strIngredient3':'Lime juice','strIngredient4':'Midori melon liqueur','strIngredient5':'Salt','strIngredient6':'','strIngredient7':'','strIngredient8':'','strIngredient9':'','strIngredient10':'','strIngredient11':'','strIngredient12':'','strIngredient13':'','strIngredient14':'','strIngredient15':'','strMeasure1':'1 1/2 oz ','strMeasure2':'1/2 oz ','strMeasure3':'1 oz fresh ','strMeasure4':'1/2 oz ','strMeasure5':'\n','strMeasure6':'\n','strMeasure7':'\n','strMeasure8':'\n','strMeasure9':'\n','strMeasure10':'\n','strMeasure11':'','strMeasure12':'','strMeasure13':'','strMeasure14':'','strMeasure15':'','dateModified':null}]}";
        }
    }
    internal class Drink
    {
        public Drink(string idDrink, string strDrink, string strCategory, string strInstructions){}
        public string idDrink { get; set; }
        public string strDrink { get; set; }
        public string strCategory { get; set; }
        public string empty { get; set; }
        public string strInstructions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've got the value from the site that you've mentioned (http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=15679) 
it seems that the JSON is invalid and after changing the text of \"granita\" to have different quotation marks everything worked!

the manual string modification that I've made is just like:

```
response = response.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: The api request that u used worked just fine for me, I have no clue.. same code, no changes.

Comment: That is not giving me any exceptions, I Made some edits to the main post. Check them please.

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced your code with some minor changes and it works fine as far as I can see. Please note the use of the `using` statements which is a good practice when using `IDisposable` objects and the way the object is constracted (I've used the wonderful [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) tool for it):

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RootObject root = new RootObject();
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = wc.DownloadString("http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita");
            root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(root.drinks.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Drink
{
    public string idDrink { get; set; }
    public string strDrink { get; set; }
    public string strCategory { get; set; }
    public string strAlcoholic { get; set; }
    public string strGlass { get; set; }
    public string strInstructions { get; set; }
    public object strDrinkThumb { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient1 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient2 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient3 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient4 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient5 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient6 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient7 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient8 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient9 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient10 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient11 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient12 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient13 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient14 { get; set; }
    public string strIngredient15 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure1 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure2 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure3 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure4 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure5 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure6 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure7 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure8 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure9 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure10 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure11 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure12 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure13 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure14 { get; set; }
    public string strMeasure15 { get; set; }
    public object dateModified { get; set; }
}
// used http://json2csharp.com/ to get an object from the json string
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Drink> drinks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I try to acces a item in the drinks variable using : Console.WriteLine(drinks.drinks.Count); 

I still get a error once every time because getting the JSON failed or is incomplete.

Comment: look at my edit. I've added a variable to hold the result and once the parsing is done I print it to the console

Comment: I ran your code 3 times, the 3th time it gave the same error as I had with my code..

Comment: I edited again. now using a much cleaner approach. tested it 10 times in a loop with a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` delay and it works fine.

Comment: I think it was because of the tcp client, since you are using web client now?

Comment: For me both of the methods worked. But the `WebClient` one is much cleaner. notice that you don't need the `getRequestCoctail` method now.

Comment: I removed the redundant method from my answer. Did my solution helped you or are you still having problems?

Comment: This worked! but that is because you are using WebClient. The problem was : HTTP 1.1 was being used (Can split packages, so I will get a incorrect JSON) HTTP 1.0 can't split packages. So I will always get a correct JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was with some special characters. I made this js function and my problem was solved:

```
treatSpecialCharacters : function(str) {
        if (!str) { return ; }
        return str
            .replace(/\x40/g, '%40') // @
            .replace(/\x2A/g, '%2A') // *
            .replace(/\x2B/g, '%2B') // +
            .replace(/\x2D/g, '%2D') // -
            .replace(/\x2E/g, '%2E') // .
            .replace(/\x2F/g, '%2F') // /
            .replace(/\x5C/g, '%5C') // \
            .replace(/\x3E/g, '%3E') // >
            .replace(/\x2C/g, '%2C') // <
            .replace(/\x26/g, '%26'); // &
    }

parms.email_padrao_sorteio = this.treatSpecialCharacters($('#txtCadastroEmailSorteio')[0].val());
```